# Git branch naming: what does ' (single quote) mean in branch name?

Tags: git, branch

In the [`git-rebase` docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase), they use a single quote (`'`) in the branch names often.

The only comment made on this naming convention (from what I can see) is:

> in which `A'` and `A` introduce the same set of changes, but have different committer information

Can anyone add more information on:

- Are there any other use cases for the `'` naming convention?
- What does "different committer information" mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those aren't *branch* names.  Those are ways to represent commit hash IDs.

Commit hash IDs are big and ugly and difficult for humans: for instance, is <sup><sub>`2e36527f23b7f6ae15e6f21ac3b08bf3fed6ee48`</sub></sup> the same as <sup><sub>`2e36527f23b7f6ea15e6f21ac3b08bf3fed6ee48`</sub></sup> ?  But commit hash IDs are how Git actually *names* commits.  A branch name just holds *one* commit hash ID—that of the *last* commit in the branch.  Each commit in turns holds one more hash ID: that of the *previous* commit.<sup>1</sup>  That's how Git finds all the commits: by starting at the ends, and working backwards.

When you use `git rebase`, Git must *copy* some commits, as if by using `git cherry-pick`.  (Many rebase operations literally do use `git cherry-pick` but some are fancier or different.)  If we have some commit with some big ugly hash ID, and we copy it to a new-and-improved commit, the new commit will *definitely* have a new and different hash ID, because *every* commit has a *unique* hash ID.<sup>2</sup>  So, to show that commit `A'` is a copy of `A`, the rebase documentation uses that single quote.  It's actually a representation of the [prime symbol from mathematics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_(symbol)).

> Are there any other use cases for the ' naming convention?

Many, but not in Git; see the linked Wikipedia article.

> What does "different committer information" mean?

Every commit has two chunks of person-and-date/time information attached to it.  Git calls these the *author* and the *committer*.  Typically these are the same, but if I copy *your* commit, my copy will have you as the author, and me as the committer.  If I copy my own commit, my copy will retain me as author and committer, but the copy will have a new committer date-and-time stamp.

---

<sup>1</sup>Some commits, which we call *merge commits*, hold two or more previous-commit hash IDs.  At least one commit per repository that has any commits is the *very first* commit and has *no* previous commit hash ID, too; we call this a *root commit*.  It's possible to put more than one root commit in a repository, but it's a bit tricky and therefore not all that common.

<sup>2</sup>Technically, hash IDs only have to be unique in commits that might ever meet.  If two commits will never meet, they could share a hash ID, as a sort of doppelgänger.  But in practice this never happens anyway.